# How to download a file from a website to a web server in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webserver, download

I have a website that is hosted by GoDaddy (Windows server hosting). I would like to be able to download a file from the internet (e.g. http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SIRI&d=11&e=27&f=2012&g=d&a=8&b=13&c=1994&ignore=.csv) directly a folder hosted on the web server (e.g. App_Data). Maybe this involves FTP? I am using ASP .NET 3.5 and C#.

EDIT: The issue I am having is how to download the file DIRECTLY to the server, not how to download the file. As the web server requires permissions, it is not as simple as downloading a file to a local machine. Also, the code will be running from the web server itself.

EDIT: This isn't cron job.

UPDATE: So, the ASP application is running on the GoDaddy server (that is hosting my website). I am trying to be able to download the file directly to that server with the application. Below is the code I have tried. This code compiles fine, but, after upload to the server, it gives me a Runtime Error.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string URL = @"http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SIRI&d=11&e=19&f=2012&g=d&a=8&b=13&c=1994&ignore=.csv";

        System.Net.WebClient downloadSite;
        downloadSite = new System.Net.WebClient();
        downloadSite.DownloadFile(URL, @"ftp://<ftp user name>:<ftp password>@<ftp ip address>");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have the file downloaded to the server without any problem wherever you want to save it without the need of FTP, but unless it is a dedicated server, or you can run jobs or scheduled tasks it will be a manual process instead of automatic.

Comment: the best way to get some help here is to perhaps show what you have tried on your own.. start here http://www.googl.com and search for C# how to download a file from a website

Comment: "Unfortunately, our Windows hosting will not support Cron Jobs. You can accomplish this through our Linux hosting. With a Virtual Dedicated or Dedicated Windows server, you can use Automated Tasks. This however will not be supported in our shared hosting." Godaddy support: http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/schedule-tasks-on-windows-host/

Comment: @HanletEscaño I believe you understood nothing about the question...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I understood the question and what he meant. I think he just does not want to download the file from a page, like the solution you offered, but that he want's the file to be downloaded at certain times like a task and without any user interventaion.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `WebClient.DownloadFile` method:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This example will

```
        string uri = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SIRI&d=11&e=27&f=2012&g=d&a=8&b=13&c=1994&ignore=.csv";
        var httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse();
        var httpStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream("D:\\test.csv" , FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            httpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
```

will download and save it to a file